# JSON not deserialized to object when doing AJAX post to MVC action

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, post

I would like to start of by saying I have tried most of SO answers on this matter and they do not address this issue.

I have a problem when posting to my controller action via jQuery ajax request.

This is my JSON object:

```
var service = {
        ServiceID: $('#ServiceID').val(),
        ServiceName: $('#ServiceName').val(),
        ServiceActive: $('#ServiceActive').val(),
        ServiceDescriptionShort: $('#ServiceDescriptionShort').val(),
        ServiceDescription: $('#ServiceDescription').val()            
    };
```

This is my class:

```
public class ServiceJson
{
    public int ServiceID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string ServiceName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public bool ServiceActive
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string ServiceDescriptionShort
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string ServiceDescription
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

This is my action(it does nothing for now but that's not the point):

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("edit")]
[ValidateJsonAntiForgeryToken]
public JsonResult Edit(ServiceJson service)
{
    return Json("", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Finally, this is my ajax request:

```
$.ajax(
{
    type: 'POST',
    url: '@Url.ActionWithoutData("edit", "service")',
    data: JSON.stringify(service),
    headers: {
        "__RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
    },
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function (responseData) {
        $('#ServiceID').val(responseData.ServiceID);
        $.snackbar({ content: 'Successfully saved.' });
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        $('#errorMessage').html(xhr.responseJSON.Message);
        $('#error').modal('toggle');
    }
});
```

My problem is that this JSON object is not serialized into my class. Clearly the names correspond. I am sure I'm missing something trivial as I have tried with simple parameters like passing just name(and of course changing the action parameter to correspond to it) without luck. I can see in the Request object that I am recieving my data but it is not being deserialized to my object.

In browser I can also see that the object is being passed correctly.

[image]

Help!

Comment: Just `data: service,` and remove `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',`, `processData: false,` and `contentType: false,`

Comment: On your action parameter ServiceJson service is null?

Comment: ActionWithoutData to Action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove these below and you should be good to go.

dataType: 'json',
processData: false,
contentType: false,

The processData shouldn't give you any issues in this case.

The dataType" 'json' is wrong since you're sending a string and not JSON. Note the JSON.Stringify() call.

"contentType: false" doesn't make send to me here :p

Comment: This did the trick. I must say I do not quite understand all of these parameters and how they translate to MVC.

Comment: `dataType" 'json'` is NOT wrong and can/should be retained - the `dataType` option specifies what is received from the server and the method is returning json!

Comment: @StephenMuecke it's in JSON format but it's a string and not a JavaScript object. The content-type denotes that the string should be read and derserialized as a JSON object.

Comment: What does that have to do with my comment - which is about `dataType` not `contentType`!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using default .Net JSON Serializer, you have to change the naming of your service object from pascal case to camel case:

```
var service = {
    serviceID: $('#ServiceID').val(),
    serviceName: $('#ServiceName').val(),
    serviceActive: $('#ServiceActive').val(),
    serviceDescriptionShort: $('#ServiceDescriptionShort').val(),
    serviceDescription: $('#ServiceDescription').val()            
};
```

Comment: This is not true. Naming convention doesn't have anything to do with this problem.